# REST calls between applications

Tags: 2013, rest, authentication

I have a series of SharePoint applications, one being our Intranet site and one being a system for serviceinformation on our IT-systems (itstatus).

I really want to make a section of out intranet FrontPage dedicated to the latest serviceinformations.

I tried making a rest call to the site (itstatus) through a CEWP placed on the intranet FrontPage - but the REST call fails!

If I enter the REST URL in my browser it looks up the content just fine: http://itstatusshp.mysite.dk/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('It-driftstatus')/items

Is there some kind of authentication that needs to be sent with the REST call for it to Work? My user has administration rights on both applications.

Thanks

Comment: You would be breaking [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), but you can get through that with a proxy (or hacking the web.config on the target, then use CORS), but it happens that SharePoint apps have this built in, called [web proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895.aspx) - so my question is; do you have apps installed?

Comment: No. No apps installed. But I have found the solution that I have to set up CORS for the application with the endpoint through PowerShell.

Comment: do you mind sharing the solution? If it does not alter IIS (web.config or additional module or similar) I would love to see it.

Comment: It is excactly altering the web.config

Comment: ugh ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is to run this PowerShell script on the web application providing the information:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0
$localFarm = Get-SPFarm
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://XXX---URL_OF_PROVIDING_WEBAPP---XXX"

# Remove old web.config modifications of MyAuthenticationProvider
$oldMods = @();
$webapp.WebConfigModifications | ? { $_.Owner -eq "CrossSiteScripting" } | % { 
$oldMods = $oldMods + $_
}

$oldMods | % { 
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Remove($_) 
}

# update the Web Application and apply all existing web.config modifications - this executes the "remove" actions from above
$webapp.Update()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

#Wait until web.config modifications finished by timer job
while( (Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.Name -eq "job-webconfig-modification"}) -ne $null ) {
Write-Host "." -NoNewline
Start-Sleep 1
}

# New web.config modifications for MyAuthenticationProvider
$myModification1 = new-object   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin' [@value='http://XXX---URL_OF_RECEIVING_WEBAPP---XXX']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"

#0 = for the enum value "SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin' value='http://XXX---URL_OF_RECEIVING_WEBAPP---XXX' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Request-Method'][@value='GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Request-Method' value='GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Request-Headers'][@value='Content-Type,Authorization']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Request-Headers' value='Content-Type,Authorization' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'][@value='true']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' value='true' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$webapp.Update()
#Wait until web.config modifications finished by timer job
while( (Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.Name -eq "job-webconfig-modification"}) -ne $null ) {
Write-Host "." -NoNewline
Start-Sleep 1
}
```